# Re-indexing repository in eclipse Ubuntu

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin

I just install git repository and install EGit plugin for eclipse. When I change the code and try to save, eclipse starts to re-index the repository. However this process never ends and eclipse becomes slower. I just search the web and try to apply some of proposed solutions but they do not work. Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

What version of egit are you using?  I believe that this is a bug that has been fixed in the Kepler milestone versions of egit.  Install the latest from here and I would bet that your problem would go away:

```
Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
```